# extracting alpha numeric string from customer speech

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am working on a voice bot at the moment. I am having difficulty in extracting pan card number (hazwr2312g). Customer can give it in many different ways. for example they can say my pan id is (hazwr2312g).

I have created a regex based on pan rules, which is working fine /[a-z]{3}[abcfghljpte][a-z][0-9]{4}[a-z]/i and extract pan number.

However, when the customer is giving pan number via voice then "g" is often replaced by "ji" (hazwr2312 ji) in the end of sentence.

various utterances:

1) my pan number is hazwr2312 ji
2) hazwr2312 ji is my pan number
3) it is hazwr2312 ji
4) hmm ahem my id is hazwr2312 ji

so-forth

how can I tackle this? Please guide me

Regards
Meet

Comment: You need to know the rules about pan card. how these pan card numbers patterns are. if you know these rules than you can search. without them it's not possible

Comment: The PAN structure is as follows: AAAPL1234C: The five (5) first characters are letters, followed by four (4) numerals, and the last (10th) character is a letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try by using `regex` or you also opt `split`, `indexOf` etc, if you having particular type of keyword that coming all the time or common.